# Use .targets to replace file in NuGet package

Tags: nuget

I have a NuGet package that depends on another NuGet package but I want to replace one of the unmanaged DLLs with one of mine.  This works well, but now I'm trying to add support for both x86 and x64 using a .targets file.  When my target application builds, it pulls down the original version, not the replacement.

Here's my .nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.2">
        <dependency id="YourPackage" version="1.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyPackage.targets" target="build\net452" />
    <file src="..\lib\x86\thepackage.dll" target="lib\net452\x86" />
    <file src="..\lib\x64\thepackage.dll" target="lib\net452\x64" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Here's my .targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="PlatformCheck" BeforeTargets="InjectReference"
    Condition="(('$(Platform)' != 'x86') AND  ('$(Platform)' != 'x64'))">
    <Error  Text="$(MSBuildThisFileName) does not work correctly on '$(Platform)' platform. You need to specify platform (x86 or x64)." />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="InjectReference" AfterTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86' or '$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
      <Reference Include="MyPackage">
        <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(Platform)\thepackage.dll</HintPath>
      </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: If I change the .nuspec...

```
<file src="..\lib\x86\thepackage.dll" target="lib\net452" />
<file src="..\lib\x64\thepackage.dll" target="lib\net452" />
```

... then it pulls down my version but uses x86 for both x86 and x64 builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by putting the files in the build folder and then simply copying the target file.

.nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackage</id>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5.2">
        <dependency id="YourPackage" version="1.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="MyPackage.targets" target="build\net452" />
    <file src="..\lib\x86\thepackage.dll" target="build\net452\x86" />
    <file src="..\lib\x64\thepackage.dll" target="build\net452\x64" />
  </files>
</package>
```

.targets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="PlatformCheck" BeforeTargets="InjectReference"
    Condition="(('$(Platform)' != 'x86') AND  ('$(Platform)' != 'x64'))">
    <Error Text="$(MSBuildThisFileName) does not work correctly on '$(Platform)' platform. You need to specify platform (x86 or x64)." />
  </Target>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)$(Platform)\thepackage.dll">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```